# Guidance to create a catalogue app for iOS

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am in the process of creating an iOS app for a catalogue app that I created for Android which you can see it here (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynmk.bonbonup) or here if you don't have an Android phone (https://appetize.io/app/ctxjvzhu56fjh01dw89urmvq9g)

I want to create an iOS app that is similar to the one I did for Android using JSON files to retrieve the images and info of the product as you can see in the GridView in the Android app. I create the JSON files through a JSON editor online and then upload the files to a webhost file manager in which all images and JSON files are kept.

My experience with Xcode is not too much and I am still in the learning curve by checking the tutorials in tree house and searching through the web.

I have been reading about UICollectionView to create a GridView similar to the one I have in the Android app but my main question would be, will it work with the JSON files I have created?

Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you just need to parse the JSON and create usable objects from it. 

Unfortunately that's as detailed of an answer I can give based on your very vague question, which is basically: "will it work with json?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply... yeah its quite vague since I am trying see which is the best way to implement JSON and what type of tools should I use. Any advice on how to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can use JSON with Swift no problem. There is a built in tool to serialize JSON.

```
let parsedDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(yourJSONData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:

Comment: Thanks! Going to check it out.